# Getter method not being triggered when being called as a hash Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have overrided a field getter inside a model so it can do some stuff when accessing that field, but it seems to be it's not getting triggered when I access the field as if my model were a Hash, example:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

      def field_name
          p "Yeah printing"
          self.field_name_before_type_cast
      end
 end
```

if I do `g = Group.first.field_name` it prints in console `Yeah printing` but if I do `g = Group.first['field_name']` it only returns the field after the type cast and doesn't execute the function that overrides the attribute.

How could I override a field so when it gets called as if my model were a hash or the normal way, it always returns the field before the type cast?

Comment: I'm not sure it will work, but you might try Group.first.send(:field_name).

Comment: @BrunoFacca It works as expected, anyway this is not the solution to my problem

Comment: Why would you expect that overriding one method changes the behavior of a completely different, unrelated method, anyway?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Python backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overrode the `field_name` method. That changes the behavior of the `field_name` method. And only the `field_name` method. It does not magically change the behavior of any other unrelated methods.

You are calling the `[]` method, which you didn't override. Ergo, its behavior doesn't change. If you want to change the behavior of the `[]` method, you need to override the `[]` method, not some other, unrelated method.

[Note: actually, you didn't override it. You *overwrote* it. That's not really a clean way to do it, but unrelated to your problem.]

I would suggest that you override the methods instead of overwriting them, and that you override both. Something like this:

```
module WithPrinting
  def field_name
    p "Yeah printing"
    super
  end

  def [](*args)
    p "Yeah printing" if args.length == 1 && args.first == 'field_name'
    super
  end
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  prepend WithPrinting
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both reader and writer methods something like this

```
def field_name
  @field_name
end

def field_name=(value)
  @field_name = your_type_casting_magic(value)
end
```